# Remote Access Software for Raspbian (ARM)

Tags: linux, remote-access, raspberry-pi, arm

I am looking for a Remote Access software similar to Teamviewer for [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/). Although Teamviewer has a Linux client, it's only for x86/x64 and not ARM. Although GUI controlling would be nice, I would settle for command line access (shell).

I tested with TightVNC and it works fine. Unfortunately my Raspberry Pi would not have a static IP. So I installed a dynamic DNS client. Although this is working fine, it would not let me access it without port forwarding on my router. This will be placed at a site where I will not be able to change router configuration.

My requirements for the software are

- Should run on Raspbian
- Support ARM architecture
- Ideally should not require port forwarding on router
- GUI/Shell access (SSH ?)

Comment: Would reverse ssh be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the instructions [provided here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5207) and [here](http://raspberrypihell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/hamachi-on-raspberry-pi.html)

Summary is.

1. Install Hamachi for Raspbian (Use logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.101-armel as the latest version does not work)
2. Create network using your LogMeIn Account.
3. Install Hamachi client for Windows
4. Install x11vnc/SSH
5. Get the IP Address using Hamachi Client and use putty for SSH or VNC Viewer for VNC.

So it's basically Hamachi + SSH/VNC.

Comment: Corray - Does Hamachi only help get the IP or can it work around firewall/ port issues the way TeamViewer does? PS: Any alternatives to Hamachi?

Comment: - Corray - Does Hamachi only help get the IP or can it work around firewall/ port issues the way TeamViewer does? PS: Any alternatives to Hamachi?